# Ubuntu freezes. After relogin using (ctrl alt f1) I get black screen but mouse works

Tags: ubuntu, freeze

Ps: I am a newbie to Linux and don't know where to start debugging or what to look for.

The problem is pretty simple. I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed. It's a new installation and I was trying out stuff. I installed some gnome shell extensions. I installed popi os windows tiling functionality. I installed latest Nvidia drivers (Nvidia driver 440) which was recommended for Nvidia rtx 2070 super. I installed restricted extras. That's it.
 Now my Ubuntu is freezing after using my system for sometime. After I press ctrl alt F1, I can go to the login screen. Mouse works at this point. Then I login again and I see a black screen. Mouse still works. At the login screen I am even able to power off and reboot as well.

I am unable to begin any debugging as I have no clue as to how to do that.

Comment: The first thing is to find out if the logs have information on the problem. You can press Ctrl-Alt-F2, that will take to a text-only console. There, do a `sudo dmesg | tee milog` (that will show the log and save it so that you can see later from the GUI and add to your question the relevant lines at the end. It's most likely an issue with the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Let me get the freezing issue again.. I will try this. Hope, soon.

Comment: So It froze again and this time. I tried ctrl alt f2 but nothing happened. I tried ctrl alt f1 I go to the login screen. There I am able to use ctrl alt f2 which just leads to a blank screen with mouse pointer. The pointer is not frozen. That's it

Comment: I used ctrl alt f3 to get to a console

Comment: Ok, from there try the `sudo dmesg | tee mylog`. By the way, consider going back to the old driver, unless you really need the Nvidia one.